# Java ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

The following code outputs

```
[[100, 200, 300], [100, 200, 300]].
```

However, what I expect is

```
[[100, 200, 300], [100, 200]],
```

Where am I wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();        

    inner.add(100);     
    inner.add(200);

    outer.add(inner);
    outer.add(inner);

    outer.get(0).add(300);

    System.out.println(outer);

}
```

Comment: Try using `outer.add(new ArrayList<String>(inner));`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You are adding a reference to the same inner `ArrayList` twice to the outer list. Therefore, when you are changing the inner list (by adding 300), you see it in "both" inner lists (when actually there's just one inner list for which two references are stored in the outer list).

To get your desired result, you should create a new inner list :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();        

    inner.add(100);     
    inner.add(200);
    outer.add(inner); // add first list
    inner = new ArrayList<Integer>(inner); // create a new inner list that has the same content as  
                                           // the original inner list
    outer.add(inner); // add second list

    outer.get(0).add(300); // changes only the first inner list

    System.out.println(outer);
}
```

Answer (score 52):

Before reading this answer you may want to familiarize yourself with [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32010172)

---

This is what you have now

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

will create

```
outer -> []
inner -> []
```

which creates two *separate* lists and stores reference to them in variables `outer` and `inner`.

---

After

```
inner.add(100);     
inner.add(200);
```

your situation looks like

```
outer -> []
inner -> [100, 200]
```

---

Here comes confusing part

```
outer.add(inner);
outer.add(inner);
```

Here *value* of `inner` variable (so *reference* to list [100, 200]) is placed in `outer` list two times. This means that `outer` "points to" [100, 200] list two times

```
//note: `reference1` == `reference2` (like 42 == 42) since they point to same object
outer -> [ reference1, reference2 ] 
              |             |
      +-------+             |
      +---------------------+
      ↓
inner +-> [100, 200]
```

This means that if you change state of list [100, 200] you will be able to see these changes using `outer.get(0)` or `outer.get(1)` or `inner`, since all of them are reference to same list.

So if we use

```
outer.get(0).add(300);
```

the `outer.get(0)` returns reference to same list as `inner` and `add(300)` adds new element to that list. Which means that after it new situation will look like

```
outer -> [ reference1 , reference2 ]
              |             |
      +-------+             |
      +---------------------+
      ↓
inner -> [100, 200, 300]
```

That is why when you print `outer` you are seeing

```
[[100, 200, 300], [100, 200, 300]]. 
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   from get(0)      from get(1)
```

---

What you actually need is to create separate list so `reference1` and `reference2` will point to two separate lists. Something like

```
outer  -> []
inner1 -> [100, 200]
inner2 -> [100, 200]
```

which will be later organized into

```
outer -> [ reference1 , reference2 ]
              |             |
       +------+             |
       ↓                    |
inner1 -> [100, 200]        |
                            |
       +--------------------+
       ↓
inner2 -> [100, 200]
```

You can do it this way

```
List<List<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> inner1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> inner2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

inner1.add(100);
inner1.add(200);

inner2.add(100);
inner2.add(200);

outer.add(inner1);
outer.add(inner2);

outer.get(0).add(300);

System.out.println(outer);
//Output: [[100, 200, 300], [100, 200]]
```

Comment: the visuals are everything

Comment: Really nice visualisations, +1 for that! But there is a small typo: it should be `from get(**1**)` instead of `from get(**2**)`.

Comment: @winklerrr Thanks. Updated :)

Answer (score 10):

The command `outer.add(inner)` adds a *reference* to `inner`, not a copy of it.

So, when you add two references to `inner` to the `ArrayList outer`, you're adding two of the same thing. Modifying `inner` through `outer.get(0)` also modifies the value in `outer.get(1)`, because they refer to the same thing.

If you create a copy of `inner` and use that instead, then you'll have two different instances and be able to modify them separately. You can do this with a simple command:

```
outer.add(new ArrayList<[var type]>(inner));
```

The instruction for `new ArrayList(inner)` creates a *new* `ArrayList` with the contents of `inner` inside of it - but doesn't use the same instance as `inner`. Thus, you'll retain the content, but not retain the duplicated reference.

By adding the new copy instead of the reference, you can modify the copy without modifying what you might call the "original."

Answer (score 0):

Try this example in IDE:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ext = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    String[] arr = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
    int n=arr.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        ArrayList temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++){
            temp.add(arr[j]);
            // this the line that needs to look at. Rather than pointing to the same memory reference creating a new ArrayList will store it in a different memory location. If you just add temp then it will point to same memory location.
            ext.add(new ArrayList<String>(temp));
             // Comment above line and uncomment below to see the difference    
            //ext.add(temp);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(ext);
```