# Add elements of one ArrayList to another ArrayList

Tags: java

Is it possible to add the elements of one Arraylist to another Arraylist?
For example if an Arraylist has elements 3,6,3,8,5 in index 0,1,2,3,4,  now I want to add 3,6,3,8,5 to another ArrayList in index 0, is it possible?

```
ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
 num.add("3");
 num.add("6");
 num.add("3");
 num.add("8");
 num.add("5");
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
 for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++)
 {
        result.addAll(i,num);   
 }
```

I have tried this but it is not working.
what i want is when i try `System.out.println(result.get(0));`
result must be [3 6 3 8 5].

Comment: Please explain what you want.  I suspect people are confused.  What do you want `result` to be after you're done?

Comment: Check this link for ArrayList of ArrayList
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147799/java-arraylist-of-arraylist

Answer (score 35):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
    result.add(i, num.get(i)); 
}
```

Or maybe just this:

```
result.addAll(num);
```

---

What your current code does is you add all of `num` to `result` many times ... at successive starting positions.  That is ... strange.

---

**UPDATE**

> What i want is when i try `System.out.println(result.get(0));` result must be `[3 6 3 8 5]`.

Ah ... I get it ... you are trying to create a list of strings where the strings are representations of the input lists:

Do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
    result.add(i, num.toString()); 
}
```

This will give you the output you are asking for.

Another possibility is that you want a list of lists of strings:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
    result.add(i, num); 
}
```

That will *also* give you the output you are asking for ... though for a different reason.

Comment: this simply copy element from one Arraylist to another. what i want is to copy element of num to result in index 0.

Comment: @koshishkharel Did the next intitively logig step to try work? That would be `result.addAll(0, num)`.

Comment: @glglgl  what if num takes input from file and file contains multiple line. here first line of file is 3,6,3,8,5. each line should be added in different index of result.

Comment: @stephen C  what i trying to do is read the file  containing multiple line like 3,6,3,8,5 and add it to Arraylist, my code is adding 3,6,3,8,5 in index 0,1,2,3,4 but i want to add first line in index 0 and second line in index 1 and so on. your suggestion is adding every line to index 0. what can i do?

Comment: @koshishkharel - What I suggest you do is ... >>think about it<< ... and work it out for yourself.  You are a Java programmer, aren't yoo?

Answer (score 4):

To simply copy all elements you can do

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(num);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/hs6olf)

and if you want to copy all the elements at a particular index you have to change the result ArrayList

```
ArrayList<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
result.add(0, num);   // 0 is the index
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/LsArHS)

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
 num.add("3");
 num.add("6");
 num.add("3");
 num.add("8");
 num.add("5");
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
result.addAll(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result list needs to be nested. It should have this kind of form:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can then just do that

```
result.add(0, num);
```

Comment: note that if you're using a version below java 7, you'll have to declare result like this: List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

Answer (score 1):

do not use all method if you are putting it inside a loop, you should use add

if at all you want to use addAll put it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> obj1 = new ArrayList<String>();

obj1.add("3");
obj1.add("6");
obj1.add("3");
obj1.add("8");
obj1.add("5");

ArrayList obj2 = new ArrayList();

obj2.add(0, obj1);;

System.out.println("Size of the arraylist is --> "+obj2.size());

System.out.println("Value at index 0 --> "+obj2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this sample code

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  ArrayList<String> nodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
   nodes.add(nodeList);
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialhall.com/2015/03/how-to-add-arraylist-into-another-arraylist-java-code.html