# How is Instance method delegate accessed after the instance is null

Tags: c#, .net

How is instance delegate method still accessible after the instance is set to null? The action delegate in the code below points to an instance method but the method is still available after the instance is set to null.

```
public class Work { public string Name{get;set;} } 

public class Worker
{
    public void Do(Work work)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is done.", work.Name);
    }
}

public class BatchWorker
{
    private List<Work> _works;
    public readonly Action<Work> Worker;
    public BatchWorker(Action<Work> worker)
    {
        _works = new List<Work>();
        Worker = worker;
    }
    public void AddWork(Work work)
    {
        this._works.Add(work);
    }
    public void DoWorks()
    {
        this._works.ForEach(this.Worker);
    }
}

public class Program{
    public static void Main(){
        var worker = new Worker();
        var batchWorker = new BatchWorker(worker.Do);
        batchWorker.AddWork(new Work {Name = "Task 1"});
        worker = null; // the instance is now null.
        Console.WriteLine("Target worker is null? {0}\r\n", batchWorker.Worker.Target == null);
        // How is this having access to instane method after the instance is null?
        batchWorker.DoWorks();
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT
>
> Target worker is null? False
>
> 'Task 1' is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A delegate contains a reference to the instance that it is to be called on.  The line:

```
var batchWorker = new BatchWorker(worker.Do);
```

Creates a second reference to `worker` that is stored in `Worker` action in `BatchWorker`.  Because there is still an active reference to the `worker` instance it will not be garbage collected.

Answer (score 5):

Your misunderstanding lies here:

```
// the instance is now null.
```

It's not. You just changed the *variable* `worker` to point to `null`. That does not somehow *destroy* or *nullify* the instance of `Worker`.

Maybe reading up on what variables, objects and references are would help. There was a question exactly about that not long ago: [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-a-reference/32010236#32010236)