# Clearing inner ArrayList empties outer ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Here's a simple code, where I create nested `ArrayList` that contains `ArrayList` of `String`. I found a weird thing: when I clear the inner ArrayList, sizes of inner and outer ArrayLists decrease to 0.

```
public static void  main(String[] a)
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> element = new ArrayList<>();
    element.add("1");
    element.add("2");
    arrayLists.add(element);
    System.out.println(arrayLists);

    element.clear();
    element.add("3");
    element.add("4");
    arrayLists.add(element);
    System.out.println(arrayLists);

    element.clear();
    element.add("5");
    element.add("6");
    arrayLists.add(element);
    System.out.println(arrayLists);
}
```

The output of that code is:

```
[[1, 2]]
[[3, 4], [3, 4]]
[[5, 6], [5, 6], [5, 6]]
```

I found out how to solve the problem and make output like:

```
[[1, 2]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Instead of clearing inner `ArrayList`, I initialize it again. Here's the code:

```
public static void  main(String[] a)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> element = new ArrayList<>();
        element.add("1");
        element.add("2");
        arrayLists.add(element);
        System.out.println(arrayLists);

        element = new ArrayList<>();
        element.add("3");
        element.add("4");
        arrayLists.add(element);
        System.out.println(arrayLists);

        element = new ArrayList<>();
        element.add("5");
        element.add("6");
        arrayLists.add(element);
        System.out.println(arrayLists);
    }
```

So the question is: is this intended to be like that (and what's the mechanism behind that) or is it a bug that needs to be reported? I've checked this code step by step using debugger, and I checked that outer `ArrayList` gets size 0 after `element` gets cleared.

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly normal.  You add a _reference_ to the list `element` to the outer list, not a copy.

Comment: You may also want to read [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference)