# Referencing two variable in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

Let's say I have three `ArrayList` and a HashMap as follows:

```
public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> m = new HashMap<>();
public ArrayList<JSONObject> A = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<JSONArray> B = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> C = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I do:

```
m.put(0, C);//setting values to the hashmap
C.clear();//resetting value of C
```

But this also clear the `C` inside `m` hashmap, resulting `m = [0, ""]`. Why is this the case in Java?

What I was expecting is this

```
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
int C = A+B //result is 3
```

Now if i set `A=0` this shouldn't affect the final value of `C`

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: yes it will clear it, that map holds a reference to C, and by doing .clear() you are clearing the object the map is referencing

Comment: but why? and how can i get around this?

Comment: clone/copy to a new object

Comment: Can you explain and post an answer with an example please?

Comment: Java is pass-by-value, so your ArrayList's reference is the same object as the one in the `Map`. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/715660/4793951 to see how to deep clone a `List`.

Comment: @Zircon not what i'm expecting

Comment: There is no such thing as a _reference to a variable_ in Java. Here's some related reading material: [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference)

Comment: I just want that `C` List to be reusable. So after first loop I want to clear it and re-use it again. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `C` is storing a reference to a `ArrayList` object. What you `put` into `m` is a copy of that same reference to the same object. If that's not the behavior you want, do what @zircon suggested and create and `put` a copy of the `ArrayList` referenced.

Comment: I'll appreciate an example please? With the given context above

Comment: See the link in Zircon's comment.