# Initialize array of custom class

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'd like to initialize an array of objects (contrived example)

```
class StringPair {
    String a;
    String b;
    // constructor
}

StringPair p[] = {
    { "a", "b" },
    { "c", "d" }
};
```

But javac complains `java: illegal initializer for StringPair` for definition of `p`

How should I write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `new` Operator inside {}. 
[difference between object and variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference)

```
StringPair p[] = {
    new StringPair("a", "b"),
    new StringPair("c", "d")
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You should invoke the constructor :

```
StringPair[] p = { new StringPair ("a", "b"), new StringPair ("c", "d") };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to create a constructor with params, you could use double brace initialization:

```
StringPair p[] = {
    new StringPair(){{
      setA("a");
      setB("b");
    }},
     new StringPair(){{
      setA("c");
      setB("d");
    }}
};
```

It seems like something you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

following list initialization (name taken from C++) is not a valid java way to init an array:

```
StringPair p[] = {
    { "a", "b" },
    { "c", "d" }
};
```

do instead use the constructor of your class:

```
StringPair p[] = { new StringPair("a", "b"), new StringPair("1", "g") };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass object's of StringPair

like below code

```
StringPair p[] = { new StringPair ("a", "b"), new StringPair ("c", "d") };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Create a constructor like this

```
class StringPair {
String a;
String b;

Public StringPair(string a, string b)
{
this.a=a;
this.b=b;
}
}
```

then you can initialize it like this

```
StringPair p[] = { new StringPair("a", "b"), new StringPair("c", "d") };
```

Comment: mark it as answer if it solves  your problem, thanks :)

Comment: how is this different from other answers? do not post duplicate answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why so many people keep posting the same solution.

In my case, I needed to initialize an array of objects. However, these objects were generated from XSD, so I'm not able to add a custom constructor. We'd need C# with partial classes for that.

Pau above gave me the hint to solve it, but his solution doesn't compile. Here's one that does:

```
StringPair p[] = new StringPair[] {
    new StringPair(){{
      setA("a");
      setB("b");
    }},
     new StringPair(){{
      setA("c");
      setB("d");
    }}
};
```