# Java, what is happening internally when you do object = object?

Tags: java, object, singly-linked-list, object-reference

I am implementing singly linked list in Java, and I have a problem.
In addition and removal of nodes, many people use temporary node like this:

```
public Object removeFirst() {
   Node temp = head;
   head = temp.next;
   Object returnData = temp.data;
   temp = null;
   size--;
   return returnData;
}
```

Why is this temp node necessary? At first glance, I think all I have to do in order to remove first element is to change second element into head node.

So my question is that in java, what does `object= object` mean? Do 2 objects become exactly same inheriting every fields and methods?

Comment: I suspect you'd benefit from reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference/32010236#32010236

Comment: Thank you! analogies there helped a lot to get a sesne

Comment: Please edit the title so it makes more sence. I can't even begin to guess what `class = class?` supposed to mean.

Answer (score 6):

`temp` is not needed. It is used to obtain the data of the removed `Node` after the `head` variable is no longer referencing that `Node`, but that can be done without it:

```
public Object removeFirst() 
{
    Object returnData = head.data;
    head = head.next;
    size--;
    return returnData;
}
```