# Abstract Class confusion, object declaration and object reference?

Tags: java, abstract-class

```
// I've cut down the code to get to the point 

abstract class TwoDShape {

   .... constructors

   .... example variables & methods 


abstract double area();

}
```

Below is where it gets confusing, why is `TwoDShape shapes[] = new TwoDShape[4]` allowed despite the Abstract rules which should have cause a compile time error ? Why does `TwoDShape test = new TwoDShape();` or other similar construction failing to compile, causing errors ? Is it because `shapes[]` is an object reference due to it being in an array ? But isn't it an object declaration as well (considering new is also used).

```
class AbsShapes {
public static void main(String args[]) {

TwoDShape shapes[] = new TwoDShape[4];

shapes[0] = new Triangle("outlined", 8.0, 12.0);
shapes[1] = new Rectangle(10);
shapes[2] = new Rectangle(10, 4);
shapes[3] = new Triangle(7.0); 

for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("Object is " + shapes[i].getName());
  System.out.println("Area is " + shapes[i].area());
  System.out.println();
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Abstract class cannot have instances, but they can be array because when you creare an array there is no instance.

Comment: A TwoDShape is to a TwoDShape[] what an egg is to an egg box. When you create an egg box, you don't create any egg. You just create an empty box that can contain eggs. When you create an array of TwoDShape, you just create that: an array. It doesn't contain any object.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I guess my theory was right after all this thinking

Comment: "*I guess my theory was right after all this thinking*" possibly, but based on description from your question it looks like you may be confusing terms like `object` `variable` and `reference`. If that is the case consider reading [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32010172).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What cannot be created is direct instances of an abstract class:

```
new TwoDShape(); //this won't compile.
```

However, this is not creating direct instances of `TwoDShape`:

```
new TwoDShape[4]; //this is creating an array of type TwoDShape
```

The above code creates an array of `TwoDShape` type. No instance of `TwoDShape` is created. If you call `shapes[0]`, you will get `null`, meaning that there's no `TwoDShape` object created.

In other words, the type of `shapes` is not `TwoDShape`, but `TwoDShape[]`. And array types can be created using `new`.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
TwoDShape shapes[] = new TwoDShape[4]
```

creates and empty array of size four capable of storing object of type `TwoDShape`. The objects themselves are not created - in other words immediately after creation the array holds four `null`s.

Now this line:

```
TwoDShape test = new TwoDShape();
```

claas the construtor of type `TwoDShape` to create an object of that type. Since class `TwoDShape` is declared abstract, the compiler throws an error.

You may want to read those for more clarification:

- [Class vs Type vs Object](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/programmer-dictionary-class-vs-type-vs-object-e6d1f74d1e2e)
- [Arrays (Java Tutorial)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)