# Since objects are stored in heap, why arrays capacity in Java should be listed at the time of their initialization?

Tags: java

whereas in java objects' creation occur in heap , As a result of this action
 objects has a dynamic capacity in java.in this level I have an ambiguity that  why arrays capacity in Java should be listed at the time of their initialization?
thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? The size of an array is not in the declaration in java.

Comment: *"objects has a dynamic capacity in java"* Huh?

Comment: for example : int [ ][ ] arrays  = new int [3 ][ ]; or int [] arrays = new int [ 3];

Comment: Java arrays are not dynamically sized. They are fixed-size, once created. Array *declarations* don't specify a size. The size is specified when the array is *created*. --- `int [ ][ ] arrays` declares the array. `new int [3 ][ ]` creates/initializes the array.

Comment: Hey Guys : given that I want create a arrays with dynamic size.in this case I can't declare an array in the below code : int [ ] arrays =  new int [ ] , and I must declare it as below : int [ ] arrays = new int [ one constant value ];

Comment: @ehsannikkhah You can't use an array without a fixed size. But you can use an ArrayList instead of a array for this like I have explained in my answer. List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(); here you don't have to specify the size

Comment: thanks to all , but I have still ambiguity.array in java is an object , and objects created in heap for allocate dynamically memory,what's reason that arrays in java must have a fixed size ???

Comment: Objects have a fixed size, determined at creation time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203194/how-can-the-jvm-allocate-memory-for-objects-despite-the-possibility-that-they-mi

Answer (score 2):

Your question is bit confusing. But the size of the array is not defined in the array declaration. It's defined when an array is created. When you assigned a created array to your declared array variable.

You have to do this because Java arrays are of fixed size and not dynamically resized. You can use `ArrayList` instead of array if you don't want the size to be fixed.

Comment: You can declare an array reference with a null value - no need of instantiation there...

Comment: Just adding to your answer... trying to explain difference between declaration and instantiation to @ehsan...

Comment: @MustehssunIqbal Okay :)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with java. Allocating memory for arrays is almost the same thing in java as using malloc in C.

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099695/is-a-java-array-of-primitives-stored-in-stack-or-heap