# What happens when a variable is assigned with an object reference variable with both having similar types

Tags: c#, heap-memory, reference-type

I have a doubt on how reference types actually work. 
I have a class Person with two properties Name and Age. I am creating an object of Person class (objPerson1), assigning some values to both the properties and assigning that object to another of type Person (objPerson2). Now the question is after assigning when I change the Name and Age property and print them both the object shares same Name and Age which is fine as they are reference type.But when I assign null value to object itself then other object doesn't get nullified.Below is the code

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person objPerson1 = new Person();
    objPerson1.Name = "Tom";
    objPerson1.Age = 10;

    Person objPerson2 = objPerson1;
    objPerson2.Name = "Jerry";
    objPerson2.Age = 15;
    Console.WriteLine($" Person1-{objPerson1.Name},{objPerson1.Age} and Person2-{objPerson2.Name},{objPerson2.Age}");
    //Above line prints   Person1-Jerry,15 and Person2-Jerry,15
    //which is right as both are sharing same address.But when I wrote following code it confused me alot.
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person objPerson1 = new Person();
    objPerson1.Name = "Tom";
    objPerson1.Age = 10;
    Person objPerson2 = objPerson1;
    objPerson2 = null;
    //After executing above line objPerson2 was null but objPerson1 were still having the values for Name and Age.
}
```

As they are reference type and both pointing to same address if I assign null to objPerson2 ,objPerson1 should also be null and vice-versa.Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I have a document you may find useful: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

Comment: Note that "But when I assign null value to object itself" suggests a problem: you don't assign an *object* a value (null or otherwise). You assign a *variable* with a value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference/32010236#32010236 for more details.

Comment: In short: person object will be created in the memory, both your variables will have a "links"/references to that memory. when you set to null - you remove a link. Object will stay in memory until garbage collector detect it has no links then destroys it.

Comment: as both variables point to the same objects, changes to one are reflected in the other. However **assigning** some other instance - in your case `null` - is not the same as **modiyfing** an instance. So you don´t change the existing object, but simply re-reference another one - null here.

Comment: Thank you guys now I understood how it actually works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit simplified, but hopefully sufficient for you to understand:

```
Person objPerson1 = new Person();
```

Heap: memory allocated for object

Stack: `objPerson1` = address of the heap object

```
objPerson1.Name = "Tom";
objPerson1.Age = 10;
```

Heap: is being filled with values.

Stack: unchanged (still the same address)

```
Person objPerson2 = objPerson1;
```

Stack: another variable gets the same address

Heap: unchanged

```
objPerson2 = null;
```

Stack: the variable `objPerson2` gets the value `0x00000000`.

Note that `objPerson1` still has the address of the heap and the object on the heap still exists. So `objPerson1` still "works".

Comment: Explained in very easy way!

Comment: Very well explained .Thanks for your time mate @Thomas Weller

Comment: @VishalD You should accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

`objPerson2` is only a pointer to the memory allocated by the initialization of `objPerson1`. Assigning null to `objPerson2` removes this pointer. `objPerson1` still points to that memory therfore it holds it's value and does not become `null` once `objPerson1` does.

Comment: @Archer [is it not?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/)

Comment: @Archer really not sure what you meant by that comment? care to enlighten a bit? I believe you are pointing to *the*