# Using concatenate to redefine an already defined string

Tags: c#

I know a string is immutable and cannot be redefined, but in this foreach loop the string is changed multiple times by adding elements of an array.

```
var stringOfNames = "";
var arrayOfNames = new string[5] { "jack", "marry", "joe", "jimmy", "bud" };

foreach (var item in arrayOfNames)
{
    stringOfNames += item;
    Console.WriteLine(stringOfNames);

}
```

Expected:

> An error stating "Variable is already defined in this scope."

Actual:

> The string is changed by adding the other names.

Also, what's the difference between these two:

1)

```
var a = "something";
var a = "something else";
```

2)

```
var a = "something";
a+= "asdf";
```

Why does the second option work?

Comment: This is the correct behavior. Why do you expect that error message? There is no redefining here. Simply at each loop the string reference _stringOfName_ will be set to a differente string reference but the variable is still the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but in this foreach loop the string is changed

No, it's not.

The *variable* changes value, to refer to a different string on each iteration. Each of the string objects in question - both the original ones in the array and the intermediate results - stays with the same data that it had before.

Here's another way to demonstrate that:

```
string x = "ab";
string y = x;
x += "cd";

Console.WriteLine(x); // abcd
Console.WriteLine(y); // ab
```

Here the value of `x` changes to refer to a new string, but the value of `y` still refers to the original string, `"ab"`.

Basically you need to be very clear about three separate concepts:

- Variables: named storage locations which store values
- References: one kind of value, which refers to an object.
- The objects themselves

I have an [answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010236/22656) which may help clarify the differences.

Answer (score 0):

`stringOfNames += item;` does not *define* the variable `stringOfNames`, it *assigns a value* to it.

Comment: actually it assigns an object to it -- this is the exact problem the OP has -- thinking the value in the object is changed.  As Jon's answer shows that original object still exists.