# What do the two classes in this code refer to?

Tags: java

**Item** i1 = new **CD**();

I don't understand how I can instantiate an object from a class and put it in another class?
Please explain what do the classes **Item** and **CD** refer to?

Comment: `Item i1` defines variable, and allows it to hold reference to objects of type `Item`. `new CD();` creates object of type `CD` and returns reference to it which is assigned to variable `i1`. We can do it when class `CD` is subtype of class/interface `Item`.

Comment: Runtime polymorphism: It is also known as Dynamic Method Dispatch. It is a process in which a function call to the overridden method is resolved at Runtime. This type of polymorphism is achieved by Method Overriding.

    Method overriding, on the other hand, occurs when a derived class has a definition for one of the member functions of the base class. That base function is said to be overridden.

Suppose My Parent Class is like, 

Class Parent {
}

Class SubClass{
}

Class Main {

Parent p;
p = new SubClass();

// here is code from this you can call subclass method


}

Comment: You're asking "Why is `Item i1 = new CD();` allowed when `Item` and `CD` are obviously different classes?", yes?

Comment: @KevinAnderson
yes sir, and I think I got it from mr Pshemo but i don,t know what is the meaning of "hold reference" ?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32010172)

Comment: He means "hold [a] reference to...".   Or just "refer to...".  But even that only make any sense if you understand that variables in Java hold _not_ actual objects, but rather _references_ to objects.

Comment: thank you so much 
I read it and I understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Item i1` defines variable, and allows it to hold reference to objects of type `Item`. `new CD();` creates object of type `CD` and returns reference to it which is assigned to variable `i1`. We can do it when class `CD` is subtype of class/interface Item.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, `CD` either extends `Item`, or, if `Item` is an interface, `CD` implements it.