# Overwritten list values

Tags: c#, list

I want to stack matrices in a list. At first, I add copies of some matrix to the list. Later I calculate a different matrix (without adding it to the list). After this calculation all my list values changed to the new matrix.

Here is the critical snippet of the code.

```
public class Algorithm
{
    private List<int[,]> mstack = new List<int[,]>();
    private List<int> stack = new List<int>();
    private List<int> solution = new List<int>();
    private bool solfound = false;
    private int col;

    public List<int> X(int[,] Matrix)
    {
        while (!solfound)
        {
            col = HelpMethods.LeastOneColoumn(Matrix);
            List<int> rowone = HelpMethods.OnesInRow(Matrix, col);

            for (int j = 0; j < rowone.Count; j++)
            {
                mstack.Add(Matrix);
            }

            SubMethod(Matrix, solution);
        }

        return solution;
    }

    private void SubMethod(int[,] Matrix, List<int> solution)
    {
        int row = stack[stack.Count - 1];
        int[,] UpdateMatrix = HelpMethods.UpdateMatrix(Matrix, row);//CRITICAL
    }
}
```

By debugging I found that the last line of the above code changes the values of the list. I'm fairly new to C# and can't find neither the origin of the problem nor a solution to the problem.

Any help is very welcome (also concerning other potential problems with the code). Thanks in advance.

EDIT: By reading the first comments the problem is clear. I still struggle to find a suitable way to implement the following: 
I want to keep track of the matrices by storing them in order such that I can go back to a previous matrix if necessary and continuously add and delete stored matrices. All my approaches failed. How can I construct such a "memory" without running into the above problem?

Comment: "At first, I add copies of some matrix to the list" - no you don't. You add multiple references to the *same* matrix object. There's only one `int[,]` object created in the code you've shown. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010236/22656

Comment: in c# , lists and multidimensional lists (matrix ) by defult only give you a new referecence to old object if you assign to new object , so you need to copy (for lists you can use .CopyTo() method)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edited my question, since I'm struggling to find a solution to the issue.

Comment: Change your code to do what you said you did, make copies of the matrix and add them to the list.