# Is an object accessible from a previous reference after it has been upcast (in Java)?

Tags: java, oop, reference, upcasting

Say A is a parent class. Let B and C be its child classes.

```
A a;
B b = new B(args);
a = b;
```

Is the type B object still accessible via b, or has it been permanently upcast to type A?

Comment: The variable `b` and the object it refers to are not affected by your assigning the same object to `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast doesn't change the *object* at all. It just gives you "a different way of seeing the object" (viewing it as an "A" instead of a "B"). They're different views on the same object though. Any changes you make via `a` will be visible via `b` etc.

The same is true without the cast. For example, if there's a `setValue`/`getValue` pair of methods with the obvious behavior, you'd see:

```java
B b1 = new B(args);
B b2 = b1;
b1.setValue(10);
System.out.println(b2.getValue()); // 10
```

The assignment doesn't copy the object - it copies a *reference* to the object from `b1` to `b2`.

You may find [my answer explaining the difference between a variables, references and objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference/32010236#32010236) helpful too.

Comment: Oh bang-on reply! Got it within the first line. Thanks for the quick clarification, @Jon

Comment: @shadyshamus: Goodo - I've added a bit more explanation to help anyone else who finds this :)