# how to understand List<? extends Number> arr = Arrays.asList(1,2,3.1f,4.1d)

Tags: java

As we konw, we can't add any element except `null` into an list like `List<? extends Number>`, so why the sentence can be compiled, wait for your answer, thanks!

```java
List<? extends Number> arr = Arrays.asList(1,2,3.1f,4.1d)
```

Comment: Why do you think it should fail compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is not "adding" an element to a `List<? extends Number>`. Adding an element into a `List<? extends Number>` looks something like:

```
arr.add(1);
```

which doesn't compile as you'd expect.

What your code is doing is creating a list containing 1, 2, 3.1, and 4.1, using `Arrays.asList`. Then you assign that list to the variable `arr`. You never `add`ed to `arr`.

When we say "you can only add null to a list of type `List<? extends Number>`", we really *only* mean that if you have a variable of type `List<? extends Number>` (`arr` in this case), you can only pass `null` to its `add` method (or any other method that accepts its generic type parameter).

It does not mean that there is no absolutely no way to add elements to the *list object* referenced by that variable. You just can't add to it by directly calling the `add` method.

For example,

```
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<? extends Number> numbers = ints; // now numbers and ints refer to the same list
System.out.println(numbers); // prints []
ints.add(1);
System.out.println(numbers); // prints [1]
```

Comment: but the `? extends Number` does not refer to an absolutely type, why the list can contain element, and even different type element, so why, i can't understand

Comment: `List<? extends Number>` is just the type of the variable. The actual list object is created by `Arrays.asList`. What specific kind of list that creates is their implementation detail. And of course `Arrays.asList` can create lists that has elements. That's what it's designed to do. You are right that `?` does not refer to an exact type, so what? The variable's type doesn't need to tell you _exactly_ the type of object the variable refers to. @wanglong

Comment: first thanks for your comment, then what you said that we don't need to know the variable type, i can't understand, can you explain clearly. @Sweeper

Comment: @wanglong It's very hard to see what you understand and not understand. You seem to not understand the difference between objects and variables, so maybe read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference) first. You also seem to fail to understand the idea of programming to interfaces, thinking that we need to know the exact type of every object, so read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) as well.

Comment: @wanglong Once you read that, reread my answer and comment and hopefully you understand more.

Comment: i have understand what you said, but now i produce some new questions. @Sweeper

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having an import issue here, regarding util.Arrays and util.List. There are functional errors in the code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<? extends Number> arr = Arrays.asList(1,2,3.1f,4.1d);
        arr.forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
        });
    
    }

}
```

Output:
[image]