# Java- Character array accepting entire string even if declared of lesser size

Tags: java, arrays, stringindexoutofbounds

I have been trying to understand string handling techniques in Java, while I came across that my code is accepting the entire string that is initialized to the string object to a character array of lesser size than the number of characters in that string object.
My example code:

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s = new String ("Test String");
        char ch[] = new char[0];
        
        ch = s.toCharArray();
        
        for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++ ){
            System.out.print(ch[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

While I have initialized the `ch` to be of size 0, the entire string in `s` is being printed in the output. Is it not supposed to give me an error stating the array initialized is lesser than the length of the characters in the string `s`? Can someone help me if I am wrong in my understanding?

Comment: From the [JavaDoc for String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()): "**a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string.**"

Comment: At `ch = s.toCharArray();` you are *not* filling array created via `new char[0];` but assigning to `ch` reference to *separate* array created by `toCharArray();`

Comment: @RandyCasburn: Does that mean the character array size gets "overidden" from what is initialised to the length of the string when assigned using `toCharArray()`?

Comment: @learner - yes it does.

Comment: "*Does that mean the character array size gets "overidden"*", no arrays have fixed size. Once created you can't resize it. What happens here is that you are assigning to `ch` variable *separate* array. So `ch` will no longer hold reference to array of size 0, but will be holding reference to another array (filled with characters same as in string).

Comment: @Pshemo: Can you please stress on "but assigning to `ch` reference to separate array created by `toCharArray()`; I didn't clearly get this statement.

Comment: For now I suggest reading [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32010172). (BTW arrays are also considered as objects. `new` keyword creates object of *specified type* like `new Car(..)` `new Person()` `new char[0]`).

Comment: Sure. Thanks @Pshemo

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```
ch = s.toCharArray();
```

You are pointing `ch` variable to a char array created from `s` internal array

You need something like

```
ch = Arrays.copyOfRange(s.toCharArray(), 0, 1);
```

Comment: Can you please stress on this more.

Comment: Almost: you never get access to the internal array (check yourself: editing the returned array does not affect the `String`). You get a copy.

Comment: honestly, didn't realize internal array is byte[] :D