# Variable scope in recursive call in java

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, scope

I was reading recursive solution of permutation in Java. Below is the code for the same.

```java
class PermutationsRecursive {

    public static List<List<Integer>> generatePermutations(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        generatePermutationsRecursive(nums, 0, new ArrayList<Integer>(), result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void generatePermutationsRecursive(int[] nums, int index, List<Integer> currentPermutation, List<List<Integer>> result) {
        if (index == nums.length) {
            result.add(currentPermutation);
        }
        else {
            // Create a new permutation by adding the current number at every position
            for (int i = 0; i <= currentPermutation.size(); i++) {
                List<Integer> newPermutation = new ArrayList<Integer>(currentPermutation);
                newPermutation.add(i, nums[index]);
                generatePermutationsRecursive(nums, index + 1, newPermutation, result);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = PermutationsRecursive.generatePermutations(new int[] { 1, 3, 5 });
        System.out.print("Here are all the permutations: " + result);
    }
}
```

Now the variable result declared as `List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>()` in the `generatePermutations` method is passed in next line in `generatePermutationsRecursive`, and this function returns `void`.

What puzzles me is that result variable declared in `generatePermutations` and the result variable declared in definition of `generatePermutationsRecursive` function are of different scope and yet the result variable is updated and gives the permutation of the set.

I wrote a sample program with similar approach but the variable `y` was not updated and it gives me 0 which makes sense to me as the variable `y` scope is different in both functions. But I couldn't understand the above code that how variable result was updated. Below is my sample code.

```java
class Jewel {
    public static int findNum(int x) {
        int y = 0;
        temp(x, y);
        return y;
    }

    public static void temp(int x, int y) {
        while (x > 0) {
            y = y + 2;
            x--;
            temp(x,y);
        }
    }
}

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jewel j1 = new Jewel();
        int result = j1.findNum(4);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: The result *variable* isn't updated. The *object that the variable's value refers to* is updated. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172 (This really isn't about recursion at all - it's just about how variables, references and objects work in Java.)

Comment: You're confusing things here. In the first example `result` is generated at the top of the recursive call stack and a _reference_ to that list passed down. In your own code you're passing down a primitive value which doesn't work. Note: [Java is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value#:~:text=Pass%2Dby%2Dvalue%20means%20that,always%20pass%2Dby%2Dvalue.).