# What is the meaning of adding another parameter to recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static int min2(Stack <Integer> st, int min) {
        if(st.isEmpty()) {
            return min;
        }
        int num= st.pop();
        if(num<min) {
            min=num;
        }
        return min2(st,min);
```

I wrote this code for finding min value in stack and I used another parameter->int min which I'd like to get rid of & don't understand what I should ask from the user to enter to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be brought down to this iterative approach:

```
public static min3(Stack<Integer> st) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        int current = stack.pop();
        if(current < min)
            min = current;
    }
    return min;
}
```

This gets rid of the parameter, but if you want to keep it recursive, you have to somehow store the current minimum. Either, passed as a parameter, or stored in a static variable.

Also: Because parameter-objects get [passed as references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), you will destroy your stack in the process.

Comment: "Because Java is pass-by-reference" Java is **always** pass-by-value. From linked answer: "*Pass-by-value means that the value of a variable is passed to a function/method. Pass-by-reference means that a reference to that variable is passed to the function. The latter gives the function a way to change the contents of the variable.*". Because Java is always pass-by-value it makes it impossible to write method like `swap(String x, String y){...}` which after calling `swap(str1, str2);` would be able to assign *local variable* `str1` value from *local variable* `str2` and vice versa.

Comment: To be more precise, it is impossible to write `swap(x, y)` for *any* type, not only for String. Anyway to understand that "Java pass the reference by value" we may need to understand [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32010172)

Comment: What I meant to say is, that if no new stack/deepcopy gets passed, the used one will get modified. Parameters are reference types, not values.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion deals with a *partial result* in every call, and an extra termination condition. This will result in at least one extra parameter in general.

Here the parameter is the minium of the popped elements.

```
public static int min(Stack <Integer> st) {
    return minRecursively(st, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
private static int minRecursively(Stack <Integer> st, int min) {
    if (st.isEmpty()) {
        return min;
    }
    int num = st.pop();
    if (num < min) {
        min = num;
    }
    return minRecursively(st, min);
}
```

Your implementation emptied the entire stack. Better would be:

```
private static int minRecursively(Stack <Integer> st, int min) {
    if (st.isEmpty()) {
        return min;
    }
    int num = st.pop();
    if (num < min) {
        min = num;
    }
    min = minRecursively(st, min);
    stack.push(num); // Leave the stack unchanged.
    return min;
}
```