# google protocol buffers: how to define message contains ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> in proto file

Tags: java, rpc, grpc, protocol-buffers

ArrayList corresponds to repeated string:

```
message m1 {
    repeated string mylist = 1;
}
```

How to define ArrayList< ArrayList< String>     > in message?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147799/java-arraylist-of-arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need another message to represent the inner List.

```
message M1 {
  repeated M2 mylist = 1;
}

message M2 {
  repeated string mylist = 1;
}
```

Of course, you may add as many fields as you'd like to M2, and you'll need some separate conversion logic to assemble the `List<M2>` into an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

You may even want to create a reusable message to represent a list of strings:

```
message M1 {
  repeated StringList mylist = 1;
}

message StringList {
  repeated string value = 1;
}
```